# React dynamically List week based on Pre and Next

Tags: reactjs, date-fns

I am new to react I try an calendar I have Next and Previous And calendar I want show Week list form Today to next seven days On click  the from that next seven days on click previous show before seven days and from selected from calendar want to Setdate and form seven Days wanted show as Same logic.
If back day are not form that condition  and picked from Calendar will not working .Please Give An idea are Any reference Thanks for Help

codeSandBox:https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-poincare-fytvk?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the while loop inside renderCells.

Take the `startDate` from the state of the component, rather than setting it every time.

Update the `startDate` when the next and previous controllers/buttons are clicked.

Updated Codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-monad-94ozg

Working example : https://94ozg.csb.app/